# Damage to drill through torque?

Tags: motors, torque, drilling, heat

I've got a Bosch PSB 50 drill, which I'm using to drill through some apparently really tough wood. I don't know why, The drill seems to be struggling, and at times comes to a complete stop. I'm not sure what exactly is happening, maybe the drill isn't powerful enough, maybe there's a piece of metal inside, or perhaps the drill bit is full of junk. Whatever the case, the drill is struggling, but it is getting through, bit by bit. The motors getting awfully hot though, and I think this is a brushed motor, so now my question: Can it be damaged by this, ie. should I get a stronger drill, or can I attempt to brute force it until I get through?

Comment: Yes, motors can obvioulsy overheat and get damaged. What hole size and depth are you trying to drill? Is the drill sharp? Is the drill specifically made for wood (i.e. is it not made for any other material it might run into?).

Comment: Looking at your drill specs: 3.3lbs, 3000RPM, 500W input. That's on the very low end. At least it didn't have enough torque to break your wrist when it binded. The part that blows my mind is your drill has a 1/2" chuck. That's comically large for such a drill. The 1/2" chuck drills I see draw 746W and are geared down to 800RPM/1000RPM and weight 4.5lbs/6.7lbs. Your drill has even less weight and power than the 1/4" chuck drills I see which run at similar speeds but draw 746W and weigh 4.5lbs. I like a keyed 3/8" drill geared to ~1200RPM. Not too massive but good torque. Don't need the speed.

Comment: For hardwood, it is not rare that the drill worked extremely hard without being able to advance. Before giving up the drill, try using a smaller drill bit, then enlarge the pilot hole to the correct size. Also, not all drill bits are created equal, often some are more expansive for a reason - tougher and sharper.

Comment: Repair or replace the drill. Can't imagine wood stopping a twist bit.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Yes, it does, especially for deep holes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first thing to check is the sharpness of the bit tip. a dull bit will not drill worth a d*mn and just waste your battery power. Note that it only takes one brief encounter with something hard to wreck the tip of a drill bit. Bits are cheap compared to your time- go out now and buy a sharp one, or get your bit resharpened!

Cordless electric drills from quality manufacturers like Bosch and Makita have a temperature sensor inside them which is supposed to automatically shut down the drill when the motor gets too hot.